# C - Convert long int to signed hex string

Tags: c, integer, hex, typeconverter

**MASSIVE EDIT:**

I have a long int variable that I need to convert to a signed 24bit hexadecimal string without the "0x" at the start. The string must be 6 characters followed by a string terminator '\0', so leading zeros need to be added.

Examples:
[-1 -> FFFFFF] --- 
[1 -> 000001] --- 
[71 -> 000047]

**Answer**
This seems to do the trick:

```
long int number = 37;
char string[7];

snprintf (string, 7, "%lX", number);
```

Comment: Just for clarification, what you you mean by signed hex, e.g. what should -1 be converted to?

Comment: FFFFFF (if I have done my conversion right :s)

Comment: OK, that looks like conversion to unsigned long and printing an unsigned hex number.

Comment: So you actually want a 24-bit hex string?

Comment: Two other questions... Is your char output buffer 6 characters or 6 characters *PLUS* a terminating zero?  Also, do you want 1 to convert to '1\0' ('1' followed by a NULL char) or to '     1' (that's supposed to be 5 spaces then a '1') or to '000001' ?

Comment: The `%lx` conversion requires an `unsigned long` but you are passing it a `long`.  Although it's working for you as-is, a cast to `unsigned long` is required for formal correctness.  Your current method will also give the wrong values for most negative numbers - eg try -256.

Comment: Your absolutely right, it doesn't seem to work properly for negative numbers.

There seems to be alot of talk of "masking" in the answers. How exactly does that work?

I am converting into signed 24 and 32bit hex strings, would I use different masks for each? How do I find out which mask to use (because people are providing differing answers)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you only want six digits, you are probably going to have to do some masking to make sure that the number is as you require. Something like this:

```
sprintf(buffer, "%06lx", (unsigned long)val & 0xFFFFFFUL);
```

Be aware that you are mapping all long integers into a small range of representations. You may want to check the number is in a specific range before printing it (E.g. -2^23 < x < 2^23 - 1)

Comment: This is the only *complete* answer right now (the conversion to `unsigned long` is required).

Comment: What determines what mapping you append?

Say I was after a 32bit (8 character string), what mapping would you add then? (Obviously you'd change the format flags to 08 too)

Comment: Effectively, the mapping is x -> x (mod 2^24), so numbers >2^24 wrap around. With eight character, 32 bit string, it would be x -> x (mod 2^32) whether this is an injection (reversible) depends on how big unsigned long is on the platform in question.

Answer (score 10):

Look at `sprintf`. The `%lx` specifier does what you want.

Comment: Furthermore, you should use `snprintf` rather than `sprintf` if you can.

Answer (score 2):

Use `itoa`. It takes the desired base as an argument.

Or on second thought, no. Use `sprintf`, which is standard-compliant.

Answer (score 1):

In the title you say you want a signed hex string, but all your examples are unsigned hex strings.  Assuming the examples are what you want, the easiest way is

```
sprintf(buffer, "%06X", (int)value & 0xffffff);
```